# defining Postscript procedures with global scope

Tags: pstricks

How can I define a Postscript procedure whose definition survives page breaks, that is, which has global scope? Here is a trivial example, where the procedure invocations after a `\newpage` fail during `ps2pdf` conversion:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}
test
\pstVerb{/printany {256 string cvs print (\string\n) print} def}

\pstVerb{12345 printany}  % works
\pstVerb{(john) printany} % works

\newpage
test
\pstVerb{12345 printany}  % printany undefined
\pstVerb{(john) printany} % --"--

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way for global definitions of simple or composite Postscript objects, such as procedures and arrays, to be made at any place in the document. In this way content of Postscript variables that e. g. hold results of calculations can be used later in the document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\pstVerb{%
  true setglobal    % global allocation mode for PS objects
  globaldict begin  % following definitions being put in the global dictionary
    /printany {256 string cvs print (\string\n) print} def
%   more definitions to follow
  end
  false setglobal
}

\begin{document}
test
\pstVerb{12345 printany}

\pstVerb{ %global definition of array variable
  true setglobal
  globaldict /somearray [(john) (linda) (albert) 5678] put
  false setglobal
}
\pstVerb{somearray 1 get printany} % linda

\newpage
test
\pstVerb{somearray 3 get printany} % 5678

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, how to define a global constant, for example, `\pstVerb{/theta 30 def}`? I have tried to use `true setglobal` before `/theta` but it seemed not to work.

Comment: `true setglobal` only sets global allocation mode (global memory); the variable itself must be put into `globaldict` (global namespace). Thus you must say `\pstVerb{true setglobal globaldict /theta 30 put false setglobal}` or `\pstVerb{true setglobal globaldict begin /theta 30 def end false setglobal}`

Answer (score 7):

You can write the definition with the environment `filecontents` into an external file and then read it by `\pstheader{file}`.

See http://tug.org/mailman/htdig/pstricks/2006/004226.html for an example

Comment: Thanks, this works well! I wonder whether I could add procedure and variable definitions to `globaldict` at any place in the document, as `\pstheader` only works in the LaTeX preamble. I would like to be able to store postscript calculation results in postscript variables that can be used later in the document.

Comment: I have nö Running TeX System for the next three Werks, so I can Not Test ansteigt. Howeverr, nodes are saved globally and you can Save variables in the Same Way.