# How to define a global constant or a global RPN function without \pstheader?

Tags: pstricks

I want to put

```
\pstVerb
{
    true setglobal
    globaldict begin
    /side 4 def
    /potocar {2 copy cos mul 3 1 roll sin mul} bind def
    end
    false setglobal
}
```

in the preamble instead of in `pspicture` to make it global.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewBorder=12pt
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}

\pstVerb
{
    true setglobal
    globaldict begin
    /side 4 def
    /potocar {2 copy cos mul 3 1 roll sin mul} bind def
    end
    false setglobal
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{pspicture}(-0.2,-0.2)(8,5)
\pstGeonode[PosAngle={180,225,-45,0},CurveType=polygon]
    (!0 side){A}
    (!0 0){B}
    (!80 sin 2 exp side mul 40 sin div 70 sin div 0){C}
    (!80 sin side mul 30 sin div 20 potocar){D}\pause

\psset{linecolor=red}
\pstLineAB{A}{D}\pause
\pstLineAB{B}{D}\pause

\psset
{
    linecolor=magenta,
    linewidth=0.5\pslinewidth,
    arcsep=\pslinewidth,
    arrows=<->,
    MarkAngleRadius=1.0,
    LabelSep=0.75,
}

\tiny
% A
\pstMarkAngle{B}{A}{D}{$\theta$}\pause
% B
\pstMarkAngle{C}{B}{D}{$20^\circ$}\pause
% D
\pstMarkAngle{B}{D}{C}{$50^\circ$}\pause
\pstMarkAngle{A}{D}{B}{$30^\circ$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I asked [AlexG](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1053/alexg) about it in [a comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63513/defining-postscript-procedures-with-global-scope/63604#comment138980_63604), he [responded it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63513/defining-postscript-procedures-with-global-scope/63604#comment139399_63604) but it seemed not to work.
I got a compilation error saying that "/undefined in side" in either `dvips` phase or `ps2pdf` phase. I am not checked which phase produced the error exactly but `latex` successfully compiled it.

Comment: Even if you put the definitions into the `pspicture` environment, they will be globally accessible afterwards.

Comment: No. Then it is local to the physical page (or overlay in beamer).

Comment: We are still on the same physical page (`frame`). Try putting `\pstVerb{(value of /side:) print side ==}` on a fresh `frame`.

Comment: @AlexG: Oh I see. I misunderstood your term "physical pages" that I meant as a PDF page. :-)

Comment: Ok. I should edit my second comment to `frame` instead of `overlay`. Since beamer repeats the `pspicture` environment and hence the definitions inside `\pstVerb{...}` on every overlay, `side` and `potocar` are always redefined (locally on each overlay!) and therefore available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `preview` package is the culprit. It seems to discard anything outside `\PreviewEnvironment` (`pspicture` in the present case) from being put into the Postscript output. I checked the PS output. The definitions of `side` and `potocar` didn't make it into it. If you remove the `preview` related lines everything is ok.